# How can I close Multiple Pdfs at the same time

Tags: pdf

I have lots of pdf opened(40-50). I want to close all pdfs at the same time, not one by one.

Comment: What program did you use to open them?

Comment: What desktop environment (Unity, GNOME, KDE)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send a regular kill signal to all instances of the PDF reader application.

First, identify your application name. For GNOME default PDF reader is `evince`, for KDE this is `okular`. Now, kill all of those processes you own using `pkill`, like this:

```
pkill -u gert evince
```

To kill all `evince` processes owned by me (`gert`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` to find all the process and kill it using the below command

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep ".pdf" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why kill with signal 9? Standard signal 15 should be sufficient to close an application. Additionally, you don't need a complicated chain of commands when there's `pkill`. I suggest to take a look at my answer.

Comment: @gertvdijk Yes. 15(SIGTERM) can be used. But here I have used 9(SIGKILL) to kill process and to ignore any File IO operation that can be handled at the kernel level. kill -9 for sure kill :)

Comment: For a simple PDF reader it won't do much damage, but don't make this a habit. It can do serious harm (corruption) when you kill processes uncleanly, similar to cutting the power of your machine without a proper shutdown.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest solution is to go to Task Manager/Processes/Apps and close Adobe there. That will close all open pdf files.

Comment: SystemMonitor/Processes